# How to covert to table with column name in comma sperated text in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My text as like following

```
'id=32702, reservationno=H11985W021216, supconfnumber=-, supitinerary=,'
```

It should be can access like following

```
select 
  id, 
  reservationno, 
  supconfnumber,
  supitinerary 
from created_table
```

I have used following query,but it not getting column name.

```
select a[1], a[2], a[3]
from (
  select string_to_array('id=32702,reservationno=H11985W021216,supconfnumber=-,', ',')
) as dt(a)
```

Comment: where that text resides?..

Comment: That text created using java program, we can arrange it any other format if required. we have column name and values. Also I have used PostgreSQL 8.4.0 version

Comment: I belive you want to add redshift tag then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this, but DO block returns void so you cannot use it directly this way. This only constructs text of the query dynamically.

```
do $$
declare
    s_sql_start text := 'select ';
    s_sql text := s_sql_start;
    _rec record;
begin
    for _rec in (
        select * from (
            select 
            substr(splitedtext, 0, position('=' in splitedtext)) as column_name,
            substr(splitedtext, position('=' in splitedtext)+1) as column_value
            from (
                select trim(regexp_split_to_table(mytext, ',')) as splitedtext
                from (
                select 'id=32702, reservationno=H11985W021216, supconfnumber=-, supitinerary=,'::text as mytext
                ) src
            ) spl
        ) filtered where nullif(column_name,'') is not null)
    loop
        if s_sql<> s_sql_start then
            s_sql := s_sql||', ';
        end if;
        s_sql:=s_sql ||quote_nullable(_rec.column_value)||' as '||_rec.column_name;
    end loop;
    raise notice '%',s_sql; 
    --will only show query text, DO block returns void so you cannot see results from in 
end;
$$
```

Comment: Any possibility this sql run and return as record ?

Comment: you have to put it into function in database - this can return record(s) - DO block is limited in usage

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
substring(b.a1 from 0 for position('=' in b.a1)) as column1,
substring(b.a2 from 0 for position('=' in b.a2)) as column2,
substring(b.a3 from 0 for position('=' in b.a3)) as column3
from 
(
select a[1] as a1 , a[2] as a2, a[3] as a3 from  string_to_array('id=32702,reservationno=H11985W021216,supconfnumber=-,', ',') a 
) as b
```

Comment: This is good, But column name pick from text. Text array size also dynamic.

Comment: @ThusithaIndunil the text size doesn't matter. `string_to_array`, `substring` and `position` will take care of it according to your sample input string FORMAT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
col1 TEXT;
col2 TEXT;
col3 TEXT;
s_sql TEXT;
BEGIN
select
substring(b.a1 from 0 for position('=' in b.a1)),
substring(b.a2 from 0 for position('=' in b.a2)),
substring(b.a3 from 0 for position('=' in b.a3)) 
INTO col1, col2, col3
from 
(
select a[1] as a1 , a[2] as a2, a[3] as a3 from  string_to_array('id=32702,reservationno=H11985W021216,supconfnumber=-,', ',') a 
) as b;

s_sql := ('select ' || col1 || ', ' || col2 || ', ' || col3 || ' from test');
EXECUTE(s_sql);
END $$;
```

Comment: column size should pick dynamically. It may change text by text.

Comment: Then you have to add a loop around the inside sql statement. The array also can be looped for creating the executing sql query.